# How to sign MSIX package with certificate that accepted on Windows Dev Center

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, azure-pipelines, windows-dev-center

I'm trying to publish an app to Windows Store using Azure Pipelines, the problem is the self-signed certificate is not accepted on the store, while I can publish the package using Visual Studio.

How can I make it work.

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(buildPlatform)" 
                  /p:AppxPackageDir="$(appxPackageDir)" 
                  /p:AppxBundle=Always
                  /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload
                  /p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=true
                  /p:AppxPackageOutput=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\***.msix'
  displayName: 'Package the App'


- task: store-flight@0
  inputs:
    serviceEndpoint: 'PublishToWinStore'
    appId: '***'
    flightName: 'Beta'
    packagePath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\***.msix'
    force: true
    skipPolling: false
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps#configure-package-signing

Answer (score 0):

For this issue , as stated in the documentation:

> To sign the MSIX (or .appx) package the pipeline needs to retrieve the
>   signing certificate. To do this, add a **DownloadSecureFile** task **prior**
>   to the VSBuild task. This will give you access to the signing
>   certificate via signingCert.

```
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: signingCert
  displayName: 'Download CA certificate'
  inputs:
    secureFile: '[Your_Pfx].pfx'
```

For details ,please refer to the link mentioned by **Access Denied** in comment.

Comment: I used this task and succefuly signed the package, but when uploading to the stored it rejects the package because of the certificate?!

Comment: ```
##[error]Submission status for "applications/***/flights/***/submissions/***" failed with CommitFailed
##[error]Reported errors: 
##[error]  InvalidParameterValue: Invalid package family name: ***.*** (expected: ***.***)
##[error]  InvalidParameterValue: Invalid package publisher name: CN=***, O=***, C=SA (expected: CN=***)
##[error]  InvalidParameterValue: Appx packages (including previously published and currently uploaded) must be uniquely identified by their full names. You have provided two packages with the full name ***.***_0.4.24.0_Neutral_ which have different contents. 
```

Comment: @NihalChandwani No, We ditched windows apps and converted to PWA using JS.